# RestAssured assertThat, wildcard for key

Tags: rest-assured

I have an object like this,

```
{
  "john": {
    "number": "123"
  },
  "sarah": {
    "number":  "123"
  }
}
```

It is an object where a persons name is the key for an object, like a map.

In restAssured how can I test for a ValidatableResponse that any number whether it belongs to john or sarah matches a certain value. In this case I know there will only be one person but an "any" matcher seems appepriate here.

I have tried `assertThat().body("*.number"), Matchers.is("myValue)`" but it does not work and gives an error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is extracting value from a json with dynamic key (the person name, in this case). There are NO built-in functions in Rest-Assured can help you.

To solve it

1. you can use [JsonPath jayway](https://github.com/lucas-nguyen-17/JsonPath/tree/master) to extract list of `number` by using deep-scan feature
2. then use `hasItem` assertion of Hamcrest.

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;

@Test
void name() {
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"john\": {\n" +
            "    \"number\": \"123\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \"sarah\": {\n" +
            "    \"number\":  \"123\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";

    List<String> numbers = JsonPath.read(json, "$..number");
    assertThat(numbers, hasItem("123"));
}
```

---

Note:

- Please don't confused 2 JsonPath classes here. One is in Rest-Assured, one is in JsonPath jayway.
- I have to say that I hate the json structure like this, it's better if using array to group items.

```
[
  {
    "name": "john",
    "number": "123"
  },
  {
    "name": "sarah",
    "number": "123"
  }
]
```